# How to get debug information when developing tick script for kapacitor?

Tags: kapacitor

I am wondering if during tickscript development, there is any opportunity to dump the stream state after passing through the processing node (log to the file, stdout)?

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking for a bit more. I'm not sure I totally follow what you're asking

Comment: There is a log node, but I prefer to write the data back to InfluxDb. We have a separate influx db just for this purpose with a 1 day retention policy so that data doesn't build up.

Comment: You can pull Kapacitor [stats via REST API](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.1/api/api/#tasks) and load them into InfluxDB. I wonder if InfluxData will release a Telegraf plugin for this - seems like a natural progression.

Answer (score 6):

I found it useful putting `|httpOut('id')` for debugging purposes. Later you can access `http://kapacitor-host:9092/kapacitor/v1/tasks/<task_id>/<httpOut_id>` and see what data is passing through that node.

Answer (score 3):

Kapacitor has a [Log Node](http://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.2/nodes/log_node/) that allows you to dump the stream state to the Kapacitor log files.

In use, it would look something like the following:

```
stream.from()...
  |window()
      .period(10s)
      .every(10s)
  |log()
  |count('value')
```

Answer (score 2):

Running `kapacitor show TASK_NAME` command should show you some information about the task itself but under the `DOT:` section there's a [graph description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) which contains stats about how many data points reached which node.

Another way of debugging would be using [`InfluxDBOutNode`](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.2/nodes/influx_d_b_out_node/) to store the points and see what's being processed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to dump data from within a tick script into a separate database...

```
stream
    |from()
        .database('telegraf')
        .measurement('cpu')
        .groupBy(*)
        .where(lambda: "cpu" == 'cpu-total')
    |eval( lambda: 100.0 - "usage_idle" )
        .as('usage_util')
        .keep()
        .quiet()
    |InfluxDBOut()
        .create()
        .database('debugging')
```

Then I use Chronograf explorer to view the results...